# Using a php string as an argument in javascript function in a while loop

Tags: javascript, php, string, function, arguments

I am trying to create a javascript function where the first argument is a number and the second arg is a string. My code is below, I have added a comments here to make it easier to read.

```
while ($dbsearch = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run_query)) {

    //define 3 vables. Example $dbu = 'Bill.Gates'
    //Example $id = 123
    // example $func using the values above should say add(123,'Bill.Gates')

    $dbu = $dbsearch['Username'];
    $id = $dbsearch['PlayerID'];
    $func = "add(" . $id . ",'" . $dbu . "')";

    //this is a string to output the results of an SQL search. It is working fine. The 
    // $func is inserted toward the end in the submit button.

    echo "<tr><td>" . $id . "</td><td>" . $dbu 
    . "</td><td><input type='submit' id='PlayerAdded" . $id 
    . "' value='Add' onclick='" . $func . "'></input></td></tr>";
}
```

The purpose of the submit button is  to add a players name as a registered player in an event.

I have tried changing the `$func` variable to just output the `$id` for both arguments and that worked, but I can't get it to output a string (name of person).

How can I fix this please?

Added: Sorry if my question was not clear. I am wanting to know how to get the add function to accept a string as an argument. For example

```
add(123,'Bill Gates');
```

Comment: What is your problem? `$dbsearch['Username']` is empty?

Comment: I'm finding it hard to understand what it is you're asking

Comment: I think the problem is the quotes inside the `add` function are breaking your HTML code, isn't it?

Comment: @Peter has the key! Put it as an answer and I upvote you. The OP must to escape quotes.

Comment: Good find Peter! If you want to open a sting with double quotes and wish to use them within a string you should back slash them `\"` I would use double quotes for element arrtibutes and use single quotes to place your javascript arguments. Example `echo "<tr><td>".$id ."</td><td>".$dbu."</td><td><input type=\"submit\" id=\"PlayerAdded".$id."\" value=\"Add\" onclick=\"add('".$id."','".$dbu."');\"></input></td></tr>";`

Comment: Thank you all for your help!
Peter thank you for finding the issue! I tried using the code you suggested below but it didn't quite resolve the issue, that said, thank you all the same! Much appreciated!
@NewToJS thank you very much too! Your code did resolve my issue. To be honest I still don't fully understand how escaping the quotes works (I get the idea, just not sure when it's required)
I don't have a teacher, so most of my learning is here, youtube or trial and error, so I really appreciate all your help guys :) I'll youtube "JS Escaping quotes" to learn more.

Comment: @Tunna182 When you use php to output html elements it will replace single quotes with double quotes so your onclick attribute wasn't valid. I'm not sure why single quotes are replaced with double quotes but I found that out the hard way. If you use php to echo the input you can inspect element and you will notice the replacement of quotes. I also learn in my spare time too. It's good that you want to know the reason(s) why things don't always work rather than just copy/paste the answer/solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try commenting this line:

```
// $func = "add(" . $id . ",'" . $dbu . "')";
```

And then in your echo:

```
echo "
<tr>
   <td>" . $id . "</td>
   <td>" . $dbu . "</td>
   <td>
       <input type='submit' id='PlayerAdded" . $id . "' value='Add' onclick='add(" . $id . ", \'" . $dbu ."\');' />
   </td>
</tr>";
```

Comment: Thanks heaps for the suggestion, but this didn't fix the issue. This stopped the add button from doing anything :(

Comment: @Tunna182 but the code isn't broken if your check it with a browser debugger?

Comment: To be totally honest, I spent so long yesterday trying different changes I don't remember what was broken and what wasn't. At the moment the code in there works and that's the main thing I'm worried about. I have copy, pasted the code from @newtoJS and that did the trick for me :)
Now I have to learn about escaping quotes. I am experiencing a similar difficulty now, but will keep going with it. If I get really stuck I'll post another question.. (trying to create a function to delete a child element using instructions from w3 schools).

Answer (score 0):

You are not escape quotes.

```
$dbsearch = array(array('Username' => 'First User', 'PlayerID' => 1),
                  array('Username' => 'Second User', 'PlayerID' => 2));

echo '<table>';
foreach ( $dbsearch as $db ) {

  $func = 'add(' . $db['PlayerID'] . ', \'' . $db['Username'] . '\')';
  echo '<tr>
          <td>' . $db['PlayerID'] . '</td>
          <td>' . $db['Username'] . '</td>
          <td><input type="submit" id="PlayerAdded' . $db['PlayerID'] . '" value="Add" onclick="' . $func . '"></td>
        </tr>';
}
echo '</table>';

?>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function add( id, name ) {
    document.write( 'Id: ' + id + ', Name: ' + name );
  }
</script>
```